# Voltar $this->algo a outro valor após o uso do valor de uma atribuição anterior é uma prática errada?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte exemplo:

```
<?php

class Classe {

   public function calcula(){
      $resultado = ($this->valor * 2);
      $this->valor = $resultado;
      return $resultado;
   }

   public function valor(int $valor = 10){
      $this->valor = $valor;
      return $this;
   }

}

$classe = new Classe;

echo $classe->valor(2)->calcula();
echo '<br>';
echo $classe->calcula();
echo '<br>';
echo $classe->calcula();
echo '<br>';
echo $classe->calcula();
```

Exemplo no [ideone](https://ideone.com/0PbJ97).

Não vou usar isso pra nada, no método que eu acabei caindo nesse contexto consegui resolver de outra forma, porém fiquei na dúvida pois isso me pareceu errado:

> Caso essa seja uma solução pro que eu preciso, é uma pratica errada fazer isso em meu código ?

Comment: talvez você não iniciar `$this->valor` aconteça um erro, do resto acredito que não. exemplo https://ideone.com/fork/ry4N8r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é mais fácil usar o `__construct`, jovem?

No seu caso eu faria duas modificações: adicionaria um construtor deixando um valor padrão para a propriedade. E definira a propriedade como `protected`ou `privada` pra ela não ser alterada externamente.

```
class Classe {

    protected $valor = 0;

    public function __construct(int $valor = 0)
    {
        $this->valor = $valor;        
    }

}
```

Agora eu creio que sua dúvida seja em relação ao método `Classe::calcula`...

Resposta: Eu não acredito que seja vantajoso fazer isso em caso de um método que vai calcular. Se ele vai calcular, ele deve devolver o valor, e não alterar o valor base (a propriedade `$valor`).

Eu deixaria o método `calcula` assim:

```
public function calcula(): int
{
    return $this->valor * 2;
}
```

Agora uma coisa que você deve se perguntar não é "se é uma boa prática ou não", mas se vai ter alguma utilidade ou não a modificação do valor `$valor`.

Você deve pensar que existem vários padrões de projetos justamente para resolver problemas comuns de implementação (embora você não deva se prender a isso) e que cada situação implica numa implementação diferente.

Só por curiosidade, uma forma que poderia ser aplicada no caso acima (vejo muito dessa implementação da classe Collection do Laravel) é o padrão de imutabilidade, que consiste em retornar uma instância da própria classe com o valor de `calcula`. Nesse caso eu modificaria o método `valor` para apenas retornar um valor.

Veja como poderia ser aplicado:

```
class Classe {

    public function __construct(int $valor = 0)
    {
        $this->valor = $valor;        
    }

    public function calcula()
    {
        return new static($valor * 2);
    }

    public function valor()
    {
       return $this->valor;
    }

}
```

Uso:

```
   $calculo[0] = new Calcula(20);

   $calculo[0]->valor(); // 20

   $calculo[1] = $calculo[0]->calcula(); // Object(Classe)

   $calculo[1]->valor(); // 40

   $calculo[2] = $calculo[0]->calcula()->calcula(); // Object(Classe)
```

Comment: Eu cai num contexto onde eu precisava chamar duas sequencias de métodos da mesma classe, mas um por exemplo eu chamaria $classe->metodo1('a')->metodo2('b')->vai(), e no outro preciso chamar $classe->metodo2('b')->vai() mas, em ->vai() ele puxaria o valor de ->metodo1() definido anteriormente por isso eu precisei voltar $this->metodo1 = 'default' em ->vai() e retornar $this. Só no exemplo ali quis demonstrar de uma maneira mais prática, mas não é um método de calculo onde cai nisso.